# How to change final modifier using ASM for a method & class

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

Actual I have one method in a class as below .

```
public static final void print(String str){
       System.out.println(str);
}
```

I want to remove `final` modifier from the met hod. So after doing that, my method will look like :

```
public static void print(String str){   
       System.out.println(str);
}
```

Using ASM, we will get this info in

```
public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, 
                                 String desc, String signature, 
                                 String[] exceptions) { }
```

In the above, I think to achieve the above case, we need to play with access argument.
But access is sum of public + static + final.
How to remove only final is my problem?

Same is for a class level final modifier?

Answer (score 7):

You just have to clear the "final" bit like this:

```
public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, 
                             String desc, String signature, 
                             String[] exceptions) { 
    return super.visitMethod(
        access & (~Opcodes.ACC_FINAL), 
        name, desc, signature, exceptions);
}
```